# No matter what i try, Samba shares keep promptig for login when trying to connect via windows

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, windows-10

I am trying to create Samba shares that are fully public so anyone can access them on the network.
However no matter what config options i put in i always get prompted for a login which is not what i want.
Here is my current config:

```
[global]
        path = /home/dataserver/
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        writable = yes
        force user = dataserver
        follow symlinks = yes
        wide links = yes
        unix extensions = no
        avaliable = yes
        browseable = yes
        public = yes
        security = user
        server string = DataServer
        guest account = root
        public = yes
        avaliable = yes

[Accounts]
        description = Accounts Folder
        path = /home/dataserver/Accounts/
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        writable = yes
[Backup]
        description = Backup Folder
        path = /home/dataserver/Backup/
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        writable = yes
[Databases]
        description = Databases Folder
        path = /home/dataserver/Databases/
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        writable = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default smb.conf supplied by Ubuntu contains a parameter missing from your smb.conf. Without the override samba defaults to `map to guest = Never` which pretty much does what it sounds like it would do - Never allow guest access.

Restore the missing override by adding the following to the [global] section of smb.conf:

```
map to guest = Bad User
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```